# Cognos 10.2.1 Connecting to MySQL with JDBC

Tags: mysql, jdbc, cognos

I'm trying to create a connection in Cognos 10.2.1 to a MySQL database using JDBC driver.

The errors I've found are this:

> Unable to connect to at least one database during a multi-database attach to 1 database(s)
>
> UDA-SQL-0432 Unable to locate the gateway "libcogudajdbc".

I know this is very specific. But... Have you had this problem? How can I solve it?

Thanks

Comment: Check your driver settings. Check if Cognos really uses your driver.

Comment: It seems that correct JDBC drivers were not installed. After installing Cognos Dispatcher you need to install correct drivers to connect to your databases.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same exception recently. Sharing the fix so that it could be useful for others.

1. Check if you have created package for mysql datasource. If you are executing the query from the package for another datasource , the query will fail even if you have datasource created successfully.
2. Check if dynamic query mode was selected when you created the package. The DQM mode is required for jdbc connections.